# How to get URL list from "webbrowser" in wxpython?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I am working with a wxPython project and I used webbrowser (Convenient Web-browser controller) it ispossible to get list of urls which are opened in my web browser, for example in Google Chrome.

Comment: The source code https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/webbrowser.py suggest No! because it simply makes a call using `subprocess`. You may have to utilise a 3rd party product/browser extension combination to query the browser itself. A cursory digging about, suggests https://github.com/balta2ar/brotab might be the sort of thing you're looking for. All that said, you are opening them, so unless you need to know if they are still open, keeping track of what was opened is simple enough.

Comment: Thank you @RolfofSaxony for you valuable information.